# Unable to send large zip file using netty

Tags: netty

I want to send a large zip file from client to server and then get a reply from server to client that the file is received. I am using `io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler` to send the large file. My issue is how to know when the entire data is received at the server, since at server side, the code for reading of data seems to run indefinitely. The code at client and server side are as below :

The client code is :

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedFile;
import io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler;


public class Client {


    private Bootstrap bootstrap;

    private boolean connected;

    /**
     * Port number of the socket server.
     */
    private final int port;

    /**
     * Host name of the socket server.
     */
    private final String hostName;


    private NioEventLoopGroup nioEventLoopGroup;

    private ChannelFuture futureChannel;


    /**
     * Initialize the socket details
     * 
     */
    public Client(final String hostName, final int port) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.port = port;
        connected = false;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the host and port.
     * 
     * 
     */
    public void connect() throws GridException {

        this.bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        nioEventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        this.bootstrap.group(nioEventLoopGroup).channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                p.addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
            }
        });

        // Make the connection attempt.
        try {
            futureChannel = bootstrap.connect(hostName, port).sync();
            connected = true;       

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return connected;
    }

    public void close() {
        futureChannel.channel().closeFuture();
        nioEventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }


    public void send(final ChunkedFile file) {
        futureChannel.channel().writeAndFlush(file);
    }

}
```

The method `send(final ChunkedFile file)` of this class is used to send the file. It is called as below :

```
File file  = new File("file1.zip");
ChunkedFile chunkedFile;
try {
    chunkedFile = new ChunkedFile(file);
    client.send(chunkedFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The server side code is :

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler;

public class Server {

    private EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup;
    private EventLoopGroup slaveEventLoopGroup;
    private int packagePort;
    private ChannelHandler fileReqHandler;


    public void start() throws GridException {
        eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        slaveEventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        ServerBootstrap server = null;

        server = new ServerBootstrap();
        server.group(eventLoopGroup, slaveEventLoopGroup)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) // (3)
        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() { // (4)
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
                ch.pipeline().addLast(fileReqHandler);
            }
        })
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)          // (5)
        .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (6)

        try {
            server.bind(getPackagePort()).sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new GridException(e);
        }        
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() throws GridException {
        eventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        slaveEventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();        
    }

    public int getPackagePort() {
        return packagePort;
    }

    public void setPackagePort(int packagePort) {
        this.packagePort = packagePort;
    }

    public ChannelHandler getFileReqHandler() {
        return fileReqHandler;
    }

    public void setFileReqHandler(ChannelHandler fileReqHandler) {
        this.fileReqHandler = fileReqHandler;
    }


}
```

The ChannelHandler (fileReqHandler) defined in the above class is as below :

```
import java.io.File;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedFile;
import io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil;

public class FileChunkReqWriteHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ChunkedFile> {
    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("in channel active method");
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();

        if (ctx.channel().isActive()) {
            ctx.writeAndFlush("ERR: " +
                    cause.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " +
                    cause.getMessage() + '\n').addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChunkedFile msg)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("in channelRead0");

    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
        buf.readBytes(bytes);
    }

}
```

I have overridden the channelRead() method to read the file. The issue is that the channelRead method is getting invoked as in an indefinite loop, each time reading only small chunks of bytes. How to know when the entire data sent by the client has been read? I would like to read the entire data send from client and re-construct the zipped file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to somehow detect the end of file. For example you could write your own protocol which always has the expected length of the file as long encoded and read this on the receiving side to understand when the end is received.

Comment: I tried reading the chunk of bytes, appending to a byte array whose size is same as the size of the file being sent and tried to recreate the file using FileOutputStream. But the file thus created does not open, it is an invalid file. Is there any other way I can recreate the zip file and its contents. Could you please have a quick review through the server and client code and let me know if I am missing something? Is there any way to achieve this file transfer other than using ChunkedFile?